# Max AWS placement group capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services

What is the maximum number of instances that can be launched into an AWS placement group?

I am specifically interested in c3.8xlarges but info on limits for any instance type would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Limit is per region not per placement group. You can have a max of 20 c3.8xlarge on demand instances per AZ. Full list is in the following link.

[How many instances can I run in Amazon EC2?](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#How_many_instances_can_I_run_in_Amazon_EC2)

> Q: How many instances can I run in Amazon EC2?
>
> You are limited to running up to 20 On-Demand instances, purchasing 20
>   Reserved Instances, and requesting Spot Instances per your dynamic
>   Spot limit per region. New AWS accounts may start with limits that are
>   lower than the limits described here. Certain instance types are
>   further limited per region.

Comment: Thanks, but our limits have been raised quite a bit past 20 instances per AZ. I am interested in any limitations on placement groups in particular.